Error Trying To Store User Data Using Shared Preferences
I am trying to store user data after logging in using Shared Preferences but my code is giving me this error message:
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. 

Here is my code:
class UserPerfs
{
  static Future<void> saveUserPerfs(User userData) async
  {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userJsonData = jsonDecode(userData.toJson());
    await prefs.setString('currentUser', userJsonData);
  }
}

How can I resolve this?

you are using decode function which requires a json string
if you want to store the user object then you have to encode it instead
static Future<void> saveUserPerfs(User userData) async
{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String userJsonData = json.encode(userData.toJson());
  await prefs.setString('currentUser', userJsonData);
}

and for retrieving the data use json.decode
static Future<User> getUserData() async
{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final encodedUser=  prefs.getString('currentUser');
   return User.fromJson(json.decode(encodedUser!));
}


Assuming the user Full name with key 'fullName' was stored along user info. How do I use getUserData() to retrieve it?

final user = await getUserData();
user.fullName;

The getUserData() is giiving this error: Functions marked 'async' must have a return type which is a supertype of 'Future'.
Try fixing the return type of the function, or removing the modifier 'async' from the function body.

It gives this Error for encodedUser: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

this because getString() retruns nullable String you can check if the result is null or not, anyway I edited the answer

I tried testing it this way:
User currentUser = User.fromJson(resBody['userData']);
//Store user data to local storage
await UserPerfs.saveUserPerfs(currentUser);
//Retrieve user stored data
final user = await UserPerfs.getUserData();
I am getting this error: 1 positional argument expected by 'getUserData', but 0 found.
Try adding the missing argument

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

jsonDecode(userData.toJson()) must be converting data to Map<String, dynamic>. You can convert to jsonString then can store in sharedPrefereces.
